# "No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'" when trying to import psycopg2

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Trying to set up my Django project to use postgres. I'm on Windows 10, using Python 3.5.1. Used easy_install to install psycopg for Python 3.5 from http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/. I was following the guide at https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/optional_postgresql_installation/index.html, but when I got to the part of trying to import psycopg2 to verify a successful installation, I get:

```
(venv) D:\Projects\webcomic>python -c "import psycopg2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Projects\webcomic\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6.1-py3.5-win32.egg\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

Not sure what to do. For what it's worth, my sys.path looks like

```
>>> pprint(sys.path)
['',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2-2.6.1-py3.5-win32.egg',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv\\Scripts\\python35.zip',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv\\lib',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv',
 'D:\\Projects\\webcomic\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: How sure are you that `easy_install` installed to the right Python installation? :) Incidentally, `pip` is superior to `easy_install` in every way. Try doing `pip3 install psycopg2` or `pip install psycopg2`.

Comment: I tried using pip originally, but it was giving me trouble. Namely...

`Command "d:\projects\webcomic\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ydlm_w4u\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\[...]\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\projects\webcomic\venv\include\site\python3.5\psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in C:\[...]\psycopg2\ `

Comment: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/ since you are using windows, download exe from this link and install

Comment: That's what I originally tried to do -- but it claimed it failed to find Python in my registry -- and then didn't allow me to select anything when it prompted me to pick a version of Python on my PC.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `venv/Lib/site-packages`, then delete any psycopg2 related file or folder there, then run this command:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

N.B. Make sure venv is still running.
To make sure it is imported correctly, run `python manage.py migrate` and it should run without any errors.

Hope I helped!